# how to create a generic popup view controller in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, xcode-storyboard

how to create a generic popup view controller that can be called by multiple view controllers with different data.
I have created a popupviewcontroller class with a label and a button.
Label and button will have different text based on call from different viewcontrollers.
In short what is proper and feasible way to create a generic pop up view that can be used by multiple viewcontrollers

```
class CustomPopUpViewController: UIViewController{


@IBOutlet weak var vWCustomSubVw: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblHeadingText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btnCustom: UIButton!

var strLblHeadingText = String()  // string for heading label
var strLblDescription = String() // string for description label
var strBtnCustom = String()// string for custom button

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)

    self.showAnimate()



    lblHeadingText.text = strLblHeadingText
    lblDescription.text = strLblDescription
    btnCustom .setTitle(strBtnCustom, for: UIControlState.normal)

}

 func showAnimate()
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    });
}


func removeAnimate()
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
        if (finished)
        {
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    });
}


}
```

and i am calling it from another viewcontroller like this:-

```
 func btnInfoTapped(){

    let customPopUpVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Course", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomPopUpViewController") as! CustomPopUpViewController
    self.addChildViewController(customPopUpVC)
    customPopUpVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(customPopUpVC.view)
    customPopUpVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)



}
```

So i want to make it generic, say it a global method or something to call same class from different Viewcontrollers

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will find that if you add examples of your code you will typically get much better responses. Even if the code is poorly written. You say you have created a class, add that as an example.

Comment: You can try this pod (https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup). It's generic to show pop up any controller

Answer (score 1):

You can create a common method to present alert controller

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AlertHelper: NSObject {

//Alert with title and dismiss button only
static func showAlertWithTitle(_ conroller: UIViewController, title: String, message: String = "" ,dismissButtonTitle: String, dismissAction:@escaping ()->Void) {

    let validationLinkAlert = UIAlertController(title:title, message:message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: dismissButtonTitle, style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
        dismissAction()
    }

    validationLinkAlert.addAction(dismissAction)
    conroller.present(validationLinkAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//Alert with title with message
static func showALertWithTitleAndMessage(_ controller: UIViewController, title: String, message: String, dismissButtonTitle: String, okButtonTitle: String, dismissAction:@escaping ()-> Void, okAction:@escaping ()-> Void) {

    let validationLinkAlert = UIAlertController(title:title, message:message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: dismissButtonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in
        dismissAction()
    }

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: okButtonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in
        okAction()
    }

    validationLinkAlert.addAction(dismissAction)
    validationLinkAlert.addAction(okAction)

    controller.present(validationLinkAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

Call this function from your Viewcontroller

```
AlertHelper.showAlertWithTitle(self, title: message, dismissButtonTitle: "OK") { () -> Void in

    }
```

Comment: Requirement is to make a Custom UI

Comment: there are lot of open source available use one or create your own by taking inspiration. Check this one https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog

Answer (score 0):

I think this pod will help you EzPopup (https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup). You can show your view controller as a pop up, easily:

```
// init YourViewController
let contentVC = ...

// Init popup view controller with content is your content view controller
let popupVC = PopupViewController(contentController: contentVC, popupWidth: 100, popupHeight: 200)

// show it by call present(_ , animated:) method from a current UIViewController
present(popupVC, animated: true)
```